# Iniciar sesión con Apple ID

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Anteriormente escribí una pregunta similar con otro tema, pero explorando mi código identifico que el otro problema y no sé por qué.

En mi aplicación estoy implementando el método de iniciar sesión con Apple solo que el problema ocurre en el dispositivo físico pero en el simulador funciona muy bien.
Este detalle es muy notable pero no sé por qué o qué es; No sé si es por alguna configuración en el dispositivo o en el proyecto, si tal vez puede ser el código, no lo sé.

Adjunto capturas de pantalla:
[image: Captura de pantalla del dispositivo en físico]

[image: Captura de pantalla del simulador]

En el simulador tengo las opciones para elegir si quiero o no compartir mi correo electrónico para Iniciar sesión con Apple.

Como dije antes, no sé qué estoy haciendo mal ni a qué se deben estas diferencias.

Adjunto parte de mi código:

```
    import UIKit
    import AuthenticationServices
    
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
       @IBOutlet weak var loginProviderStackView: UIStackView!
    
       override func viewDidLoad() {
        setupProviderLoginView()
         
        super.viewDidLoad()
       
      }
    
       @available(iOS 13.0, *)
      func setupProviderLoginView(){
         
        let authorizationButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton()
        authorizationButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleAuthorizationAppleIDButtonPress), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.loginProviderStackView.addArrangedSubview(authorizationButton)
         
      }
       
      @available(iOS 13.0, *)
      func performExistingAccountSetupFlows(){
         
        // Prepare requests for both Apple ID and password providers.
        let requests = [ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest(),
                ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider().createRequest()]
         
        // Create an authorization controller with the given requests.
        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: requests)
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
         
      }
       
      @objc
      func handleAuthorizationAppleIDButtonPress() {
         
        let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
         
        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
         
      }
    
    
    
    }
    
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension ViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate{
        
func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
            
            switch authorization.credential{
            case let appleIDCredential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:
                
                let userIdentifier = appleIDCredential.user
                let fullName = appleIDCredential.fullName
                let email = appleIDCredential.email
                
                self.saveUserInKeychain(userIdentifier)
                self.showResultViewController(userIdentifier: userIdentifier, fullName: fullName, email: email)
                
            case let passwordCredential as ASPasswordCredential:
                
                let username = passwordCredential.user
                let password = passwordCredential.password
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    self.showPasswordCredentialAlert(username: username, password: password)
            
                }
                
            default:
                break
            }
            
        }
        
private func saveUserInKeychain(_ userIdentifier: String) {
            do {
                try KeychainItem(service: "com.Gents", account: "userIdentifier").saveItem(userIdentifier)
            } catch {
                print("Unable to save userIdentifier to keychain.")
            }
        }
        
        
private func showResultViewController(userIdentifier: String, fullName: PersonNameComponents?, email: String?){
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                
               //self.camposAppleID(mail: email!, nombre: fullName!, apellido: userIdentifier)
                
                let givenName = fullName?.givenName
                let familyName = fullName?.familyName
                let Mail = email
               // print("El givenName: ", givenName!)
                
             camposAppleID(mail: Mail!, nombre: givenName!, apellido: familyName!)
    
            }
            
        }
        
        private func showPasswordCredentialAlert(username: String, password: String) {
            let message = "The app has received your selected credential from the keychain. \n\n Username: \(username)\n Password: \(password)"
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Keychain Credential Received",
                                                    message: message,
                                                    preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
        func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
            print("Falló")
        }
        
    }
    
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension ViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding {
        /// - Tag: provide_presentation_anchor
        func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
            return self.view.window!
        }
    }

KeyChainItem.swift

    import Foundation

struct KeychainItem {
    // MARK: Types
    
    enum KeychainError: Error {
        case noPassword
        case unexpectedPasswordData
        case unexpectedItemData
        case unhandledError
    }
    
    // MARK: Properties
    
    let service: String
    
    private(set) var account: String
    
    let accessGroup: String?
    
    // MARK: Intialization
    
    init(service: String, account: String, accessGroup: String? = nil) {
        self.service = service
        self.account = account
        self.accessGroup = accessGroup
    }
    
    // MARK: Keychain access
    
    func readItem() throws -> String {
        /*
         Build a query to find the item that matches the service, account and
         access group.
         */
        var query = KeychainItem.keychainQuery(withService: service, account: account, accessGroup: accessGroup)
        query[kSecMatchLimit as String] = kSecMatchLimitOne
        query[kSecReturnAttributes as String] = kCFBooleanTrue
        query[kSecReturnData as String] = kCFBooleanTrue
        
        // Try to fetch the existing keychain item that matches the query.
        var queryResult: AnyObject?
        let status = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &queryResult) {
            SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
        }
        
        // Check the return status and throw an error if appropriate.
        guard status != errSecItemNotFound else { throw KeychainError.noPassword }
        guard status == noErr else { throw KeychainError.unhandledError }
        
        // Parse the password string from the query result.
        guard let existingItem = queryResult as? [String: AnyObject],
            let passwordData = existingItem[kSecValueData as String] as? Data,
            let password = String(data: passwordData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            else {
                throw KeychainError.unexpectedPasswordData
        }
        
        return password
    }
    
    func saveItem(_ password: String) throws {
        // Encode the password into an Data object.
        let encodedPassword = password.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        
        do {
            // Check for an existing item in the keychain.
            try _ = readItem()
            
            // Update the existing item with the new password.
            var attributesToUpdate = [String: AnyObject]()
            attributesToUpdate[kSecValueData as String] = encodedPassword as AnyObject?
            
            let query = KeychainItem.keychainQuery(withService: service, account: account, accessGroup: accessGroup)
            let status = SecItemUpdate(query as CFDictionary, attributesToUpdate as CFDictionary)
            
            // Throw an error if an unexpected status was returned.
            guard status == noErr else { throw KeychainError.unhandledError }
        } catch KeychainError.noPassword {
            /*
             No password was found in the keychain. Create a dictionary to save
             as a new keychain item.
             */
            var newItem = KeychainItem.keychainQuery(withService: service, account: account, accessGroup: accessGroup)
            newItem[kSecValueData as String] = encodedPassword as AnyObject?
            
            // Add a the new item to the keychain.
            let status = SecItemAdd(newItem as CFDictionary, nil)
            
            // Throw an error if an unexpected status was returned.
            guard status == noErr else { throw KeychainError.unhandledError }
        }
    }
    
    func deleteItem() throws {
        // Delete the existing item from the keychain.
        let query = KeychainItem.keychainQuery(withService: service, account: account, accessGroup: accessGroup)
        let status = SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionary)
        
        // Throw an error if an unexpected status was returned.
        guard status == noErr || status == errSecItemNotFound else { throw KeychainError.unhandledError }
    }
    
    // MARK: Convenience
    
    private static func keychainQuery(withService service: String, account: String? = nil, accessGroup: String? = nil) -> [String: AnyObject] {
        var query = [String: AnyObject]()
        query[kSecClass as String] = kSecClassGenericPassword
        query[kSecAttrService as String] = service as AnyObject?
        
        if let account = account {
            query[kSecAttrAccount as String] = account as AnyObject?
        }
        
        if let accessGroup = accessGroup {
            query[kSecAttrAccessGroup as String] = accessGroup as AnyObject?
        }
        
        return query
    }
    
    /*
     For the purpose of this demo app, the user identifier will be stored in the device keychain.
     You should store the user identifier in your account management system.
     */
    static var currentUserIdentifier: String {
        do {
            let storedIdentifier = try KeychainItem(service: "com.Gents", account: "userIdentifier").readItem()
            return storedIdentifier
        } catch {
            return ""
        }
    }
    
    static func deleteUserIdentifierFromKeychain() {
        do {
            try KeychainItem(service: "com.Gents", account: "userIdentifier").deleteItem()
        } catch {
            print("Unable to delete userIdentifier from keychain")
        }
    }
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias!

Comment: Cuál es el error? Que no te salen esas opciones en el iPhone? Qué versión de iOS tienes en el simulador y en el iPhone?

Comment: Hola de nuevo, bicho. Gracias por escribir. En el simulador de iOS uso la 13.7 y en mi iPhone tengo la 15.0.2. De hecho, descargué el proyecto de ejemplo que proporciona Apple en su documentación para este método. Juice https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple .

Comment: Es correcto, las opciones para elegir si quiero compartir o no mi correo no me aparecen en iPhone, pero en simulador si. Pero el detalle más importante es que con el dispositivo en físico si continuo para iniciar sesión con el Apple ID los datos como el nombre y el correo me aparecen como vacios ('nil').

Comment: Siempre que ejecuto la app y que quiero iniciar sesión con el Apple ID me aparece esa vista simple a diferencia de que si lo hago con el simulador ahí ya aparecen las opciones. Sí, mi cuenta de iCloud está en mi iPhone y en el simulador.

Answer (score 1):

Algo a tomar en cuenta quizás ya lo sabes, es que solo la primera vez con tu cuenta de apple, te darán el mail y maximo nombre personal, y un token, después solo te darán token que se utiliza como pass, después si intentas iniciar con apple con esas mismas credenciales el mail u otro dato serán nulos, lo que la mayoría hace es guardar en keychain esos datos  y aparte dárselos a los servicios en este caso tu backend, por lo mismo solo la primera vez te dará las demás opciones, recuerda que estas entrando a los servers de apple, son muy quisquillosos con la info personal, lo puedes revisar en la documentación. saludos!

algo que te puede ayudar es que la info puede guardarse en el keychain del dispositivo, no los guardes usando persistencia eso es una mala practica, aparte no se recomienda guardar datos que se consideran sensibles a menos que utilizes los metodos que te recomiendan en la documentación, algo que te puede servir es lo siguiente:

```
    guard let passwordData = credentials.password.data(using: .utf8) else { return }
    
    let query: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
                                kSecAttrService as String: serviceName,
                                kSecAttrAccount as String: credentials.username,
                                kSecValueData as String: passwordData]
    
    let status = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
    
    if status != errSecSuccess {
        throw KeychainError.unknown(status: status)
    }
```

es un ejemplo pequeño, el service name es un alias por ejemplo "url.service.myApp"... , para obtener la data o revisar si ya esta guardada en el keychain puedes crear un metodo y agregar un codigo parecido al siguiente....

```
    let query: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
                                kSecAttrService as String : serviceName,
                                kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitOne,
                                kSecReturnAttributes as String: true,
                                kSecReturnData as String: true]
    
    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &item)
    
    switch status {
    case errSecItemNotFound:
        
        return Result.failure(KeychainError.passwordNotFound)
    case errSecSuccess:
        if let existingItem = item as? [String : Any],
           let passwordData = existingItem[kSecValueData as String] as? Data,
           let password = String(data: passwordData, encoding: .utf8),
           let account = existingItem[kSecAttrAccount as String] as? String {
            
            return Result.success(Credentials(username: account, password: password))
        } else {
            
            return Result.failure(KeychainError.malformedData)
        }
        
    default:
        return Result.failure(KeychainError.unknown(status: status))
    }
```

el item puedes colocarlo como optional de la clase CFTypeRef

```
    private var item: CFTypeRef?
```

tambien existen metodos para actualizar los datos o borrarlos claro, dale una revisada a la documentación, también
toma en cuenta que yo en mi caso obtengo la data en una estructura que llamé Credentials, podrías hacer lo mismo, con eso ya puedes generar tus validaciones, si no hay data en el keychain significa que el user nunca se ha registrado, ahora al hacerlo guarda la data desde el delegate que te da la info del usuario, así por si tu backend no pudo registrar, ya las tiene el keychain, ya tu evalúas tus opciones, espero esto te sea de ayuda, por otro lado para las personas que no pueden ingresar nuevamente... revisa con tu backend sus credenciales y podrían ver otras opciones, usar su token por ejemplo para hacer una búsqueda de la info y que te las de tu backend, si es que estos se guardaron en algun servidor...

Comment: Hola Yan, gracias por comentar. Pues de hecho la app ya está en la tienda y varias personas me reportan lo mismo, que al querer iniciar sesión con Apple ID la app crashea por lo mismo, que no trae los datos o los trae en nil.

Comment: si va a ser eso, agrega en los keychain la info, esta es segura te paso un buen metodo, voy a editar la respuesta saludos!

Comment: De hecho acabo de editar la pregunta con los nuevos ajustes que le hice a la app con la integración de Keychain.

Comment: veo que ya no te aparece lo de compartir correo.... a lo que veo  es por lo mismo que apple ya no te proporciona el correo y el nombre, ya que te los da únicamente la primera vez que inicias sesion con ese metodo, esos datos ya te los dará siempre nulos, como ya lo hiciste una vez, aunque borres la app, no te los va a proporcionar mas, al menos en la app en la que estoy trabajando ya no me pregunta si quiero compartir nombre y mail por que ya inicié anteriormente con ese dispositivo y mi cuenta, solo me capta el Face ID o el Touch ID, y ya.